# Flushing hosts without being able to connect to the host

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm seeing this dreaded error:

```
Host '10.0.12.34' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

The server is an RDS instance running in AWS.  There are VPC rules are such that I can only access the database with a VPN, and every user in my organization "lands" in the VPC from the same IP.  In other words, other users are failing to connect to the database server and are causing "our" IP to get blacklisted by the server.

I've tried running the command with the mysql cli binary on my machine, but since my host is blocked, I can't even connect to run the `FLUSH HOSTS` command.

Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't look like there's a way to run commands against the DB from the AWS console.  Short of spinning up an EC2 instance in the same VPC and installing the mysql client, is there any other way to flush hosts?

Comment: obs there's no other way, If your users and you land in the same IP and that IP got banned there's no way to circumvent the MySQL security, And there's no way to fire the command from the console. FWIW I think that restarting the database effectively flushes hosts. But surely you don't want to do that